# an element is not visually searchable in chrome inspection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am building a web scraper selenium but the element I want to click is actually searched in chrome inspection layout but can't be seen visually(like when you hit ctrl+F and search for an element by typing it in, it shows up in the DOM structure collapsing...)
So I can't proceed since I should make a "clicking" on it with my Python.

http://bitly.kr/Nypl88
is the link and the element I would like to click with selenium has an id called "cns_Tab21". When you search for it, the result total is 1 but can't be seen in the DOM.

Thank you for reading this post and for your answer in advance.

Comment: What is the technology rendering the HTML? Does it use the shadow-DOM? Because that may not be visible in the source (i.e. right click and view source), thus not visible to a scraper

Answer (score 0):

Your element is hidden inside an iframe.

To get to it you will need to switch to the iframe first:

```
driver.get("https://finance.naver.com/item/coinfo.nhn?code=255440");
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("coinfo_cp"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement tabElement = driver.findElement(By.id("cns_Tab21"));
```

***Edit***

Added a Python implementation

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.naver.com/item/coinfo.nhn?code=255440")
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("coinfo_cp")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
tabElement = driver.find_element_by_id("cns_Tab21")
```